# How can I convert from bytes to binary numbers in Python?

Tags: python, binary, byte, bit, converters

So I'm a total Python beginner and I got this byte object:

```
byte_obj = b'\x45\x10\x00\x4c\xcc\xde\x40\x00\x40\x06\x6c\x80\xc0\xa8\xd9\x17\x8d\x54\xda\x28'
```

But I have no idea how to put this in a binary number, I only know it's gonna have 32 bits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try `int.from_bytes(...)`, documented [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#int.from_bytes) e.g.:

```py
>>> byte_obj = b'\x45\x10\x00\x4c\xcc\xde\x40\x00\x40\x06\x6c\x80\xc0\xa8\xd9\x17\x8d\x54\xda\x28'

>>> int.from_bytes(byte_obj, byteorder='big')
394277201243797802270421732363840487422965373480
```

Where `byteorder` is used to specify whether the input is big- or little-endian (i.e. most or least significant byte first).

(Looks a bit bigger than 32 bits though!)

Comment: Thank you I didn't know about that method. What does the byteorder = 'big' do?

Comment: It's for specifying if the input bytes are 'big-endian' (most significant byte first) or 'little-endian' (LSB first). I'll update answer to include that detail.

Comment: Hi @user16350182, if the answer solved your problem, it would be great if you could [mark it as 'accepted'](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) to help others find it more easily.